# Поворот и движение объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Я новичок в Unity и недавно у меня появилась проблема: как запрограммировать 2D персонажа с видом сверху на движение вперёд и назад, при нажатии W и S соответственно, а также поворот вокруг своей оси по и против часовой при нажатии клавиш D или A, также соответственно. Если говорить конкретно, то нужен танк. Звучит, просто но у меня не получилось его повернуть.

---

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
   RotateRight();
}
```

И сам метод

```
public void RotateRight()
{
   transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 0.3f);
}
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получилось сделать?

Comment: При удерживании кнопки D или A он должен плавно поворачиваться. Какой метод за это отвечает - я не знаю.

Comment: Вы написали "у меня не получилось его повернуть" - значит вы пытались и у вас "что-то" пошло не так. Вы можете привести примеры своих попыток? Может быть ваша проблема решится 1-2 знаками, но у отвечающих нет ни малейшего представления сейчас как устроен ваш код, а значит, никто не может вам помочь. Если не понимаете, почему до сих пор вам не скинули готовый проект с анимированным 2D танком, то настоятельно прошу ознакомиться: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Mr.Linsux никакой метод за это не отвечает, в этом и суть **программирования**, были бы все всевозможные методы определены за вас, кому бы были нужны программисты?

Comment: похоже тебе нужно `Time.DeltaTime`

Comment: А как это 2D персонаж с видом сверху? 2,5D игра? Можно скриншот?

Comment: transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 0.3f); вот тут не происходит постоянного поворота как такого ..а просто назначается угол, как вариант значение Z должно увеличиваться или уменьшатся постоянно пока происходит нажатие кнопки D

Comment: посмотрите еще на `RotateAround()`  и не забывайте умножать значение на `Time.deltaTime` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Comment: Всё. Я разобрался, теперь двигается правильно. Это и правда элементарно! Буквально пара строк.